# Modify default behaviour of PropertyGrid and TypeConverterAttribute

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I am using a property grid to edit, amongst other things, a collection of items:
[image]

The default behavior for a collection provides a + button to edit each member of the array.

I am using a Form to edit this field, which is already wired up but I want to remove the ability for the user to edit the array by using the 'expander'

So it would look like this:

[image]

UPDATE1: made ProductIds an IList property instead of int[ ]
Now does this:

[image]

-----------------!

UPDATE2: made ProductIds a custom class, eg

```
 MyWrappedCollection : IEnumerable<int>
```

so it now looks like this:

[image]

Sure, it still shows [+] but it doesnt expand to anything (ie disappears when you click it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute that controls whether a property is expandable or not is it's TypeConverter. The ExpandableObjectConverter is a built in class that provides the ability to expand a property and look at it's own. I am guessing by default that arrays and collections use this converter to display what is in them.

You can write your own TypeConverter which does not inherit from ExpandableObjectConverter and set it as an attribute on your property to remove the +.

Comment: Cheers. My type converter extended ExpandableObjectConverter for some reason when should have just : TypeConverter.

Answer (score 0):

By default for a collection, it uses `[...]` method. May be you could use a collection (For example a List) instead of an array.

By the way, any specific reason you use arrays?

Comment: I made ProductIds an IList instead of int[ ] and you can still expand it. see screenshot on original post.

Comment: Apologies for the criticism, however your answer doesnt really provide much help. YES, the [...] appear but only when you click into it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement and apply a UITypeEdtitor. See [How to: Implement a UI Type Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53c49eck.aspx)

Override **GetEditStyle** of your UITypeEditor to return **Modal**

Comment: I have a UITypeEditor attribute attached to this property already. The editor overrides GetEditStyle to return Modal (as I was using it to pop up a form) however the expansion icons still appear.