# Editing array / List in property grid

Tags: c#, arrays, list, propertygrid

I have a list in the `PropertyGrid`, and an array.

When the array opened in expander (`+`) can edit it,

but when the list opens in expander can not edit it.

What is the difference between them?

I saw this question:

**[Modify default behaviour of PropertyGrid and TypeConverterAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677480/modify-default-behaviour-of-propertygrid-and-typeconverterattribute)**

that in order to prevent editing by the expander is turned array to a list.

Why in the array can to edit, and the list can not be edited?

How can I change this? (Or can not be ?)

Comment: the answer is in the linked question ... there is a different typeconverter used for arrays ... check which one ... open it in reflector to see how it's done ... write your own for List<T> ... register it ... done

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42, For my list I use in    `[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]` for expander. You know another converter that can help me? (in the array have no converter, this by default)

Comment: arrays use exactly this converter ... looks like it can't handle List ... you could subclass/build your own ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ayybcxe5.aspx

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42. But to what do I convert the list to make it possible to edit? To an array?

Comment: What type of list exactly? Do you have some code?

Comment: @SimonMourier. According to what I understand all kinds of lists can not be edited in the expander, just arrays.

Comment: Please answer my question if you want help

Comment: @SimonMourier. My question is general! Yet here is the code I used:  [Customized display of collection data in a PropertyGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert)

Comment: @SimonMourier. I saw your answer at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368646/editing-a-property-of-an-object-inside-an-object-in-propertygrid. Is when I do `ExpandableObjectConverter`  then the instances of the class become `[Browsable(false)]`?

Comment: @HodayaShalom you don't convert the list ... you have to derive a new TypeConverter and register that for the class ... that way you can tell the property grid that this "thing" is expandable ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why you can not edit,

because each value in a list is an `object` you can not edit it,

even though I put in `GetValue` one value from the object.

I opened the object in a list in expander and edited there.

Answer (score -1):

AS my suggestion it is better to use List because List is auto implemented array list which the size is flexible compare to array we need to assign it. Find out more in 
http://www.dotnetperls.com/list

Comment: But list can not be edited in expander of property grid, did you read my question?

Comment: try have a look in here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert